ROS 2 subscriber that controls RGB LEDs on a Raspberry Pi using rpi-ws281x-python
I am currently working on a robotics project where I want to control RGB LEDs (WS2811 driver) to display the current state of the robot. As the rpi-ws281x-python library needs to be run with sudo, I am having issues with the integration of the code in ROS 2 (Humble on Ubuntu 22.04).
I have a simple subscriber node that calls imported functions of the rpi-ws281x-python library whenever a new message is received.
When I launch the node without sudo, I can display the subscribed messages, but can't change the LED colors accordingly, as the library needs sudo. When I ros2 launch the nodes with sudo (in launch file), it doesn't read any subscribed topics.
Is there a clean solution that allows the execution of some imported functions (that require sudo) in a non-sudo node?

Not sure if you have seen this.
Some solutions to this problem here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85109/run-rpi-ws281x-without-sudo
Mark

This is a link only answer (albeit to a another SE site).

This should really either be a comment or the answer should try to summarise the solutions given in the other post. Although unlikely, the linked to answers or question could be deleted at some time in the future (especially given the current furore about the SE content being scrapped by AI companies and users' discontent about that). Please see What is Stack Overflow's take on link only answers?
